# AS3 ahow to control the pause button of the external swf

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I just trying to control buttons of external loaded swf .

```
var swfRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://mysite.com/player/001.swf');
var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader();
swfLoader.load(swfRequest);
var holder:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
holder.addChild(swfLoader);
addChild(holder);
```

And in main swf I created new button with Instance Name : pauseBtn , I want this button communicate to external swf witch has pause button with Instance Name : pausebtn in action script 2.0

external btn:

```
on (release)
{
    status_playing = false;
    playbtn._visible = true;
    pausebtn._visible = false;
    stop ();
}
```

Please help me how to communicate with these buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I don't think you can directly communicate between AS3 content and AS2 content. One way around it is using a LocalConnection object to handle the communication between the two.

How it would work after creating the objects and connecting them, is the main swf would send a message to it's LocalConnection object and the loaded swf would receive that message on and use it to handle whatever you need it to.

LocalConnection - AS3 Reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html

LocalConnection - AS2 Reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001176.html#312868

Comment: To add, there's [Grant Skinner's SWFBridge](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/swfbridge_easie.html) wrapper for LocalConnection

Comment: Thanks for this LocalConnection function.
but I do not want to modify this external loaded AS2 swf file. only want to control to buttons from main swf files

Comment: From the Loader class documentation, it clearly states: AS2 and AS3 can't talk to each other, and that using a LocalConnection object is how to get around it.

So again, doesn't seem to be a way to directly call AS2 code from AS3.

You'll have to use a LocalConnection object to do so. If you don't (or can't) modify the AS2 swf, you could try making an AS2 wrapper that loads your AS2 swf and implements the required LocalConnection object to act as a bridge between the two.